# YouTrack notification about new issue

Tags: notifications, youtrack

I want Youtrack to send email notification to all users in certain project when new issue with `Critical` priority is created. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Notifications in YouTrack are [based on subscriptions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/server/Notifications.html#subscriptions), which consist of a saved search query and events that trigger the notification. So you need to create a saved search like `Project: projectname Priority: Critical` and subscribe needed users to this saved search (select the **Issue created** event).

Please also note that subscriptions are set up on a per-user basis, so it would be necessary to add subscriptions for each user separately (**Users > username > Notifications > New subscription**).